# Mac audio does not work, could be hardware issue

Tags: mac, audio

Plain Mac OS X installation (10.6.8), and all of a sudden the audio stopped working. I get visual feedback upon changing volume with the keyboard, and the icon in the top right reports that audio is at full volume. Internal speakers are handling sound. Ask for more information if you need it... I'm not sure what else to give.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Activity Monitor to see if `coreaudiod` is running properly, if not there may be problems there.

You may also try re-installing Mac OS X from the discs that came with your computer, or you can install a virtual machine and run another OS through it to see if you get sound to function correctly.

If it is hardware, you could try a PRAM reset (do this before the re-install idea), if you don't know what that is then at start up hold `Cmd+Alt+P+R`, wait for four start up chimes, then stop.

You could also reset SMC, but I don't think it will do anything.

Comment: I figured this out a while after I asked and forgot to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `system preferences > sound > output` and making sure *Internal speakers* is **selected**.

Comment: And try listening through the earphone connector.  (And consider that the switch in the earphone connector may be stuck in "earphone" mode.)

Comment: Cole, did you even read the question? "Internal speakers are handling sound."

Comment: Also I will try that, DanH

Comment: @tekknolagi Yes I did read it. By internal speakers are handling sound I assumed that that meant you were expecting to hear sound from them but it wasn't working. Is that assumption incorrect?

Comment: Nope. They were selected to handle sound in the System Preferences.